# C# sending keystrokes in the wrong order to Microsoft teams

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I am physically disabled and I use Dragon professional individual to operate my PC.

I have experimented with Dragon's built in dialogue box, in the scripting language, but it is too buggy!

Therefore, I decided to build my own dialogue boxes with visual studio. Currently I have forms for building a basic SQL statement, building a SQL case statement, a generic enter text form and 1 specifically for Microsoft teams.

Each of the forms basically work in the same way-I enter text into one or more text boxes and when I click okay, I build up a long string, hide the form (so that the previous application has focus) and then I send the keystrokes.

The Microsoft teams form works slightly differently, in that it sends a "{Tab} ", 1st to enable the formatting box and therefore it handles new line characters (without having to remember to say {shift +enter}.

I will also admit to another problem (but I am not too worried about this 1 unless it's connected to my main issue). My code is not actually sending an additional "{Tab }", so although my code actually posts the message into Microsoft teams, I'm not sure why.

So in Dragon, I have a command called [Build]. The script simply runs the application I have built in visual studio, passing a command line parameter, which determines what form is actually displayed.

When I click the okay button, the following code is executed:-

```
    this.Hide();
    generateSQLSelectStatement();
    private void generateSQLSelectStatement()
    {
        //Additional keystrokes required for Microsoft teams
        generateKeystrokes("{Tab} ");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        generateKeystrokes(textBoxSomeText.Text);
    }

    private void generateKeystrokes(string keystrokes)
    {

        keystrokes = keystrokes.Replace("%", "{%}");
        keystrokes = keystrokes.Replace("+", "{+}");
        keystrokes = keystrokes.Replace("^", "{^}");
        SendKeys.SendWait(keystrokes);

    }
```

Yes some of my naming conventions are not brilliant because I have copied them from other forms.

Thanks

Comment: Is this for desktop Teams (as opposed to running it in a browser)? If so, do you have any similar issues with other Electron-based applications?

Comment: I should mention, I'm not sure how much help I can be as there's not much option to safely extend this app, so I haven't played with it much. That said, -because- it's an Electron app, it's apparently possible to actually -modify- the app itself on disk, but I haven't tried it so ymmv...

Comment: I am using the desktop application.

Comment: Have you tried to do this with any other Electron apps? If so, what has the outcome been?

Comment: This seems to be product related question, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.